# Advance java- due to servlet file generate error while run .jsp

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I face a problem regarding servlet, while m trying to run at localhost at that time if servlet is their in controller(MVC) than it will show error

> "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

but if I delete servlet file than it will run properly. 
but in project insert,up,dlt all functionality neccesary. so how can I resolve this problem with servlet

in console- "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controller/UpdateServletSave : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class controller.UpdateServletSave)
"

Comment: check the console for exception and paste it

Answer (score 1):

The `UnsupportedClassVersionError` means that you compiled your servlet class with a newer version of the JDK than the version used by Tomcat at runtime. For example, it could happen if you compiled your class with JDK 1.7.x and Tomcat is running with JDK 1.6.x.

To resolve the issue, you could either compile your servlet class using the same java version used by Tomcat, or you could setup Tomcat to use the newer JDK version that you are using to compile your servlet.

In other words: runtime JDK version must be >= compile time JDK version